# Class.forName() exception. Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)

Tags: java, swing

I have been trying to connect my java login form with access database without odbc. using ucanaccess driver.

After implementing all the instructions, all I am getting is the class.forName exception first plus many other exceptions.

```
private void btnLoginMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        // TODO add your handling code here:

         try{
                Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                String path="C:\\Users\\yamao\\Downloads\\javaJars\\ExercicesAppDb.mdb";
                String url="jdbc:ucanaccess://"+path;
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rst=st.executeQuery("select * from Users");

                while(rst.next()){
                    if(rst.getString("passWord").equals(passWordTxt.getText())){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Successful Connection");
                    }
                }
            }catch(SQLException ex1){System.out.print(ex1);}
            catch(Exception ex2){}
    }
```

I am expecting to have a login in light with data in my database

Comment: Please make a clear question, what is your goal with this? I assume that you want to fix it, then please provide more log information

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: @jpganz18 here is the exception i am getting :Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at Login.Login.btnLoginMouseClicked(Login.java:115)
 at Login.Login.access$000(Login.java:19)
 at Login.Login$1.mouseClicked(Login.java:47)
 at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)

Comment: @second please sir, i am new to java, how can do that ?

Comment: Use `ex1.printStackTrace()` and copy the result from the commandline to your question (don't put it in the commments)

Comment: Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195865/ucanaccessdriver-throws-exceptionininitializererror-caused-by-java-lang-runtime

Comment: @second thank you, the problem has been solved